# look for values within a date interval on a second data.table

Tags: r, loops, data.table, bioinformatics, lubridate

I am a beginner to R and I am looking for help with a function/loop.

I Have this data table "by_newborn":

| id_mom | date | id_newborn | week | weight | conception_date | pregnancy_interval | one_year_before_pregnany | one_year_before_interval | first_trimester |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.21e+12 | 01/05/2020 | 1234 | 18 | 2 | 2019-12-27 | 2019-12-27 UTC--2020-05-01 UTC | 2018-12-26 | 2018-12-26 UTC--2019-12-27 UTC | 2020-04-02 |
| 1.21e+12 | 01/05/2020 | 5489 | 18 | 2 | 2019-12-27 | 2019-12-27 UTC--2020-05-01 UTC | 2018-12-26 | 2018-12-26 UTC--2019-12-27 UTC | 2020-04-02 |

`by_newborn` structure:

```
structure(list(ן..ID = c(2602035392, 2602035392, 4104232942), 
    date_of_birth = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("01/05/2020", 
    "02/05/2018", "03/05/2020", "04/05/2020", "05/05/2020", "06/05/2020", 
    "07/05/2020", "08/05/2020"), class = "factor"), week = c(38L, 
    38L, 36L), conception_date = structure(c(18117, 18117, 17401
    ), class = "Date"), pregnancy_interval = new("Interval", 
        .Data = c(22982400, 22982400, 21772800), start = structure(c(1565308800, 
        1565308800, 1503446400, 1503446400, 1563062400, 1563062400, 
        1564358400, 1564358400, 1563840000, 1563840000, 1563926400, 
        1564617600, 1567728000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
        "POSIXt")), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

I have created the intervals using `Data table` and `Lubridate`

```
conception_date = lubridate :: dmy(by_newborn$date) - lubridate:: weeks(by_newborn$week)
by_newborn[, conception_date:= conception_date]
by_newborn[, pregnancy_interval := interval(ymd(by_newborn$conception_date), dmy(by_newborn$date))]
```

I have a second table I made `TSH_results` with tests results history for each id_mom:

```
id_mom  |date      |tsh_level|Units
1.21e+12|01/02/2020|0.5      |ng/dl
1.21e+12|05/02/2020|0.5      |ng/dl
1.21e+12|03/05/2015|1.8      |ng/dl
1.21e+12|09/05/2015|1.8      |ng/dl
```

`TSH_results` structure:

```
structure(list(ן..id_mom = c(1.21e+12, 1.21e+12, 1.21e+12, 1.21e+12, 
1.21e+12), date = c("01/02/2020", "01/02/2020", "01/02/2020", 
"01/02/2020", "01/02/2020"), TSH_level = c("0.5", "0.5", "0.5", 
"0.5", "0.5"), measur = c("ng/dl", "ng/dl", "ng/dl", "ng/dl", 
"ng/dl")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
),
```

I would like for some help with writing a code that will look for each ID for a result in `TSH results` that is within an interval (or 2 dates) and will return the TSH level to a new column in `by_newborn`

I have tried this, but it seems I might need a loop or another way:

```
by_newborn[id_mom == TSH_results$id_mom & (dmy(TSH_results$date) %within%
pregnancy_interval), preg_results := TSH_results$result]
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: your sample data is rubbish (please use `dput(mydata)` to provide some), so I cannot produce an answer. The best I can do: I take a look al the `foverlaps()`-function from the data.table package, and start from there. Or use a `non-equi`-join

Comment: Your second table has strings where it needs proper`Date`s. Since your question is not about converting strings to dates/timestamps, I suggest you pre-clean your data. I second the notion that this is a non-equi join, your `id_mom == TSH_results$id_mom` is wrong. In general, it might be helpful if you first understand the concept of join/merge (based on strict equality of fields), I suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3358272. After that, adapting your mindset to non-equi join takes a bit of elbow-grease, but will be less difficult.

Comment: @Wimpel Thank you, much appreciated! what is the preferred way to upload a data.table/frame here?

Comment: yes.. use the output generated by `dput(mydata)`.. when too large, select relevant rows/columns (like `dput(mydata[1:100, 2:4])`to reproduce the problem you want solved.

Comment: You're learning `dput` :-) ... the `.internal.selfref` is not usable, I suggest you remove it and wrap the `structure(.)` in setDT or as.data.table, resulting in `as.data.table(structure(...))`. Second, even if I load `lubridate`, I get the error `invalid class "Interval" object: Inconsistent lengths: spans = 3, start dates = 13`, can you please verify that pasting the `structure(.)` in your console works? If so, then it's something wrong on my end, but it would be useful to have this question be reproducible in that way. Thanks!